# Create Ticket View container

Tags: android

I need help to create ticket view, like the image, i found this library https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView, but is View not ViewGroup. My idea was to change that view by a framelayout or a relativelayout but I could not make all the content adapt to the ticket form.

Comment: Try https://github.com/mreram/TicketView

Answer (score 3):

The library you found should be alright. The idea there was that the view isn't a container because the creator didn't know if you'd like a LinearLayout, FrameLayout, CoordinatorLayout, ConstraintLayout, or one of the many many other things. What you want to do is use it as your background. You can see an example on their sample code @ https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_example.xml#L24

What they've done here is create a ConstraintLayout, set the `TicketView` as the first child (background) and had it stretch to fill the entire view, then they added other views on top of it.